# CDN Tax Receipt issuance for more than 1 donor-auto process

Tags: cdn-tax-receipts

Can CDN tax receipts be emailed directly to the donors at once- auto process?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean - the title implies "batch", but then the question body suggests you mean at the time the donor makes a contribution.

If you mean "automatically at the time the donor makes a contribution", then there is the "Attach receipts to automated workflow messages" setting in the CDN tax settings under Administer - CiviContribute. If you turn that on the donor will receive a tax receipt as soon as they finish the donation.

If you mean batch to several donors at once, if you do a contribution search, then you can select some or all, and then in the Actions dropdown there are some choices for Issue Tax Receipts.